# HTML CSS PRELOADER with either Image change with glitch effect or a few seconds video

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can you help me with a free source code for preloader
which will help me to implement in my website

I want Splash screen animation with set of images keeps changing with glitch effect
or
when site is loads for 1st time a button will appear when pressed it will load a video of maybe 10 to 15secs
and then it display:none; and it views the site

1 Condition this video loader should not appear if site is refreshed again and again
only appear if you close tab and open in a new tab.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.